# Using variables for Curl in shell command - very inconsistent

Tags: bash, shell, variables, curl

I have a curl command in a shell file that looks like below. All I do through another application is rename this file and then I execute the shell file. However, it is very temperamental. For no obvious reason it stops being able to read the variable and treats as blank. Usually (but not always) when I recreate the file it does work. I'm using Notepad++ so I don't think there are spacing or line break issues.

Thanks for your help

```
vr_id=`basename $0 .sh`
curl "https://www.test.com/control.php/info/loads/?       event=showList&wo_id=${vr_id:7}&id=all::0" -H 'Cookie: filemsg=1; var_db=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; __utma=111111.11111111.11111.11111111.1111116.12; __utmb=11111.1.10.1111111; __utmc=1111111; __utmz=111111.111111.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Host: www.test.com' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*' -H "Referer: https://www.test.com/control.php/info/loads/?wo_id=${vr_id:7}" -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'X-Prototype-Version: 1.7' --compressed
```

Comment: Maybe you have spaces in your paths? Use ``vr_id=$(basename "$0" .sh)`` to fix that.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Cygwin - hence the windows editor

Comment: The output of `echo "==$vr_id=="` prior to calling `curl` would be very useful.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko I did as you suggested but it didn't change anything. i don't think there are spaces in the path

Comment: @chepner The file name is files1_1234567.sh The echo output is exactly that, if I output it as echo ${wo_id:7} prior to calling curlthen I get 1234567 which is exactly what I want but it doesn't always work within curl.